# How to enable comment shortcuts for vscode tmllanguage?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have created my own extension having a `tmlanguage.json` file in order to get syntax highlighting for a self-defined language.

```
 "patterns" : [
    {
      "match" : "(#)(.*)",
      "name" : "comment.less"
    },
    {
      "match" : "(#)(.*)",
      "name" : "comment.line.less"
    }]
```

How can I get the comment shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure comments and other basic language features, try creating a [language-configuration.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/language-support#_smart-bracket-matching) file. This file is used in language contribution in your extension's `package.json`:

```
"contributes": {
    "languages": [
        {
            "id": "unicorn-language",
            ...
            "configuration": "./language-configuration.json"
        }, ...
    ]
    ...
}
```

The `language-configuration.json` file defines basic text features of the language. You likely need to configure `comments`:

```
{
   "comments": {
       "lineComment": "//",
       "blockComment": [ "/*", "*/" ]
   }
}
```